# Favicon shows up on rails local, not on hosted app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, favicon

I put my favicon.ico in my public folder, and it shows up on my localhost, but when I check it out on the internet, [image: other favicon] shows up instead. My app is hosted through heroku, and the domain is provided by hover. Where is this failing?

Also, in case this helps, here is the code I'm using to render the favicon:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <title>Shoulak Predictions</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
        <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Update

If I go to `mydomain.com/favicon.ico`, I do download the favicon that I uploaded. ALSO, if I go to `therealapp.herokuapps.com`, it shows up. I think somehow my domain provider may be providing their own?

Comment: can you access it directly? `http://app.com/favicon.ico` . If yes, then it's a crazy cache thing likely (try another browser or something?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing Hover forwarding, not using the DNS features. Hover automatically uses their own favicon.

Answer (score 8):

Adding a random number in your favicon will force the update:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

Comment: Nothing changed with the local server or with the web app.

Comment: Just tried it and seems to work just fine... I just replace the favicon.ico file in my public folder with a new one and then just changing the number from 2 to 3... did the trick on the next page refresh.

Comment: Well then our situations must be different, because it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Once I cleared my browser cache, the favicon showed up.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it takes time for that change to show up. Something to do with browser caches or server settings or something.

Comment: It's taken mine longer than that before.

Comment: That sucks. Regardless, where is that other favicon coming from? Is it provided somewhere, or is it a default if it's left blank?

Answer (score 0):

Please check on another browser, it will work surely. It takes time to reflect.
Below my working code.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../static/images/icon.png"/>
```