# Favicon and headers not working in custom domain for rails app with heroku and Godaddy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, favicon

I have a rails app hosted on heroku and then pointing my custom domain to it via GoDaddy.

I've been struggling to get the favicon to work and have tried everything in this post. [Favicon shows up on rails local, not on hosted app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562173/favicon-shows-up-on-rails-local-not-on-hosted-app)

I've also tried rake assets:clobber

I've also tried deleting the favicon, recompiling it, and then pushing. None of this has worked.

Before this I was getting an error about X-frames being from SAMEORIGIN that was causing my site to not render anything in the head as well as not load.

So I added this line to my application controller per another stack overlow answer

```
before_filter :allow_iframe_requests

  def allow_iframe_requests
    response.headers.delete('X-Frame-Options')
  end
```

I'm not sure if this is related or not but somehow everthing works on myapp.herokuapp.com but nothing is getting loaded in the head or source in inspector on myapp.com

Here's what it looks like.

[image: This is on myapp.com]

As you can see.. nothing is really showing up in the head.

On myapp.herokuapp.com you can see everything that is supposed to be in the head show up.

[image: All google analytics, sumome, favicon, all working...]

I'd really like to understand what's going on as this has been super frustrating. I have tried many solutions that I found here but have yet to have anything work. My hypothesis is that it's something to do with Godaddy. Yes I have cleared my cache multiple times.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try my site to generate favicons and the correct markup for them:
https://favicongenerator.co

You can upload an icon and it generates all the sizes and the correct markup for rails.

Comment: It didn't have anything to do with the favicon structure. But I like your site. Haven't been able to figure this one out yet.